# Limit Paste in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE widget that is limited to only `<p>` tags and non-block-level elements. Thus, the user is unable to insert tags like `<div>` or `<table>`. Which is the desired behavior.

However, the user can copy any content from any web page and paste it to TinyMCE. Is there a way to prevent pasting there, or better yet, limit paste to only a set of tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [paste plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/paste) shipped with TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

I know that in Drupal, if you use TinyMCE provided in the wysywig module, you get the choice of allowing filtered html, full html, or php code inputted into the editor.

Comment: That means there must be an option for this in TinyMCE. Maybe I should look at the Drupal source code?